# nginx reverse proxy 404 with proxypass to multiple hosts

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, debian-buster

I have an domain whitch i want to use to reach all of my servers.
If i browse mydomain.com, I see my nginx home page as espected.
If i type in mydomain.com/nas, I want to see my home page of my NAS.

(NOTE: I've done some more testing and replaced my original test with my new tests to advoid confusion.)

I've done some testing with two physical servers. Both these servers do not run Nginx and I'm beginning to wonder if that what I want only is possible when the proxied server also runs a reverse proxy like Nginx.

In the following code-block I show my tests and results (read the comments):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name rw-desk;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # When I uncomment one of the following lines, the redirection works normally.
        #proxy_pass http://ip_router:80/;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_router:80;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_nas:8080/;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_nas:8080;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_router/;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_router;
        
        # But when uncommenting one of the following lines, 
        #  it will redirect me correctly but the url changes to http://ip_nas:8080/
        #proxy_pass http://ip_nas/;
        #proxy_pass http://ip_nas;
    }

    # But i want to change from server using location blocks:
    location /test/ {
        # The following line returns 404 from Nginx, url changes to http://rw-desk/redirect.html?count=0.something
        #proxy_pass http://ip-nas:8080/; 

        # The following line returns blank window and the url changes to http://rw-desk/
        #proxy_pass http://ip-router:80/; 

        # the following line redirects to nas home-page and the url changes to http://ip-nas/
        #proxy_pass http://ip-nas/; 

        # The following line returns blank page and url changes to http://rw-desk/
        #proxy_pass http://ip-router/; 
    }
}
```

So just to clearify, with every test i enter http://rw-desk/test/ in my browser.

In all cases, when not adding the tailing `/`, the returned page will be an 404 page from the server itself (not nginx) as expected.

For now i've worked around the problem by adding a new server block and proxy-passing in the root directory. In the original server block i've added an `return 301 http://nas.rw-desk` inside the `/nas/` location. This works but the url will be rewritten to http://nas.rw-desk, whitch i don't want. I want the url to remain http://rw-desk/nas/.

If you know what is going on or how to fix it, i'd like to hear from you.
I run raspbarian based on Debian 10.

Comment: The URIs `/nas` and `/nas/` are different. In your second `server` block, the URI `/nas/` should be changed to `/` before being passed to `192.168.178.138:8080`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i know what you mean.
I've now tried the following:

`
    location /nas/ {
                rewrite /nas/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.178.138:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
`

but it results to the same page not found error from nginx.